# FPTAS for Number Partition Problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, partition-problem

I've been given a task to implement two algorithms (an exact algorithm and fully polynomial approximation scheme) for number partitioning problem. I found out that I can use some modification of heuristic approach (like complete differencing tree method) or just plain brute-force for the former, but I have a lot of trouble with the latter... can anyone point some resources where FPTAS for NPP is discussed or guidelines how to construct one?

Cheers

Comment: What is the "number partition problem"? [$k$-partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_k-partition_problem)?

Comment: No, it's just standard Partition problem, with two subsets having equal/nearly equal sums of their elements. "Number Partition Problem" is a term that I found in some literature (I think it's used to distinguish it from graph partitioning).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem mentions two textbooks which cover the subject:

Hans Kellerer; Ulrich Pferschy; David Pisinger (2004), Knapsack problems, Springer, p. 97, ISBN 9783540402862

Martello, Silvano; Toth, Paolo (1990). "4 Subset-sum problem". Knapsack problems: Algorithms and computer interpretations. Wiley-Interscience. pp. 105–136. ISBN 0-471-92420-2. MR 1086874.